# Plotting the development of the income in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

As am I am completey new to Power BI, I have a very basic question.
I have a table of the following form:

| Person | Income May - July |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | 1000 |
| Peter | 1400 |
| Peter | 1600 |
| Anna | 800 |
| Anna | 1800 |
| Anna | 1900 |
| Steven | 1200 |
| Steven | 700 |
| Steven | 1500 |

Now, for each person, I would like to draw the development of the income in one diagram in Power BI. But, in particular, I don't know how to separate the data for each person. I know how to plot the total income but not the development.

How can I do so?

Comment: There is a month column missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the progression over months you'll have to introduce a month column:

| Person | Month | Income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | May | 1000 |
| Peter | June | 1400 |
| Peter | July | 1600 |
| Anna | May | 800 |
| Anna | June | 1800 |
| Anna | July | 1900 |
| Steven | May | 1200 |
| Steven | June | 700 |
| Steven | July | 1500 |

Then it's straight forward to create a line chart from the table.

[image]

Comment: I did the same but the Sigma sign is missing in front of my "Income" in the fields bar. Therefore the results looks strange.

Comment: If the sigma (implicit measure) is missing, your Income column is of type text, not number.